# Facebook OAuth with mobile app and backend web server

Tags: facebook, oauth, vk

Google SignIn provides the ability to get in mobile app user ID token (see https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth). The point of this is to send this data from mobile app to external web server with further digital signature validation (so called JWT verification).

Is Facebook and/or Vkontakte have similar API? If no - then how to protect calling external web service within mobile app (prevent tampering of user ID)?

Comment: With Facebook, you would simply send the access token to the server, and then make an API request from there to get the user id.

Comment: @CBroe so I need to exchange access token for user Id by calling Facebook API at server side, right? If so what  exactly I should call?

Comment: A simple `/me` request will do, if you don’t need any additional info besides the app-scoped user id and the name at this point.

Comment: @CBroe thanks, it seems what I was looking for. Is this scheme can be used with any OAuth provider, including Google?

Comment: That’s for Facebook, I don’t know if the other providers have it working the same way.